# How to refer to an object with a long name within one scope of code?

Tags: c#, reference

I have an object that I work with, and it is placed within a lot of dictionaries and lists, so when I call it, the line gets really long, and I would like to be able to just do some things quickly using its reference, like so:

```
ref MyObject o = thingsStorageClass.dictionary[anotherDictionary[list.key]];
o.someField = value;
int i = o.integer;
DoStuff(o.specialSomething);
```

But it seems I can't just place `ref` before a local object initialization. How do I do something like this without using an external method with my object as parameter?

Comment: The `ref` keyword is used in method parameters. It is used to pass a _reference_ to a `value` type, such as `int`, `char`, `byte`, or `struct` to name a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `ref` and it will work, because `o` is an instance of class `MyObject`, so it is reference type. You won't create new instance this way.

Comment: The important part is `o.someField = value`. It just assigns to a copy, not the real object.

Comment: No, you aren't creating new copy, you just want to get reference of existing object (which is inside your dictionary etc), this will work because `o` is instance of class (reference type). So whatever you do to `o` will take place in dictionary (because it's the same object).

Comment: You can easily verify this with simple program or/and debugger.

Comment: It works. I thought some objects don't work that way. Those are probably structs and everything else that is not a class.

Comment: Yeah, those are non-reference types, which are called `value types` (e.g. `struct`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about referencing the object, you just want to assign it to a `variable` (remove the `ref` keyword and that's what you have). If you are using C# 3.0 upwards you can shorten it even further by using the `var` keyword e.g.

```
var o = thingsStorageClass.dictionary[anotherDictionary[list.key]];
```

Or if you mean the actual type itself, then you can use an alias e.g.

```
using MyPair = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
...
var o = new MyPair("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just drop `ref` - you're specifing the type anyway.

```
MyObject o = thingsStorageClass.dictionary[anotherDictionary[list.key]];
o.someField = value;
int i = o.integer;
DoStuff(o.specialSomething);
```

Or use `var o =`